# Call exported function in .so which was linked with a different libc than the program calling the function

Tags: android, linux, shared-libraries, vulkan, libc

## Situation

Let me explain my situation:

- I'm running all this stuff on Android chroot with root access and SELinux disabled
- I have a program linked against glibc in the chroot (can't relink it, since I don't have the source code)
- The program will load and call exported function from `libvulkan.so` (located in `/system/lib64/libvulkan.so`), which is Vulkan Loader, and it's linked against Android's Bionic libc
- 2 libc cannot be loaded into one program's memory at the same time. I tried that and got SIGTRAP

How can I do this (efficiently, I don't want Vulkan overhead)?

## My possible solution

Solution 1:

- Build a program (some kind of Vulkan "server") that load `libvulkan.so`, open an IPC shared memory, then export Vulkan (wrapped) function pointers to that shared memory
- Build a fake `libvulkan.so` (some kind of Vulkan "client") for the real program to load. The fake `libvulkan.so` exports the same things as real one, then redirect the call to exported functions to function pointers in IPC shared memory

Note: From what I saw on StackOverflow, it's not possible to export function pointers through shared memory.

Solution 2:

- Same as solution 1, but instead of exporting function pointers to IPC shared memory:
- Fake `libvulkan.so` (Vulkan "client") put the API name (or ID or sth like that), function argument, ... to the shared memory
- The program (Vulkan "server") run in a while loop listening for calls from fake `libvulkan.so` (Vulkan "client") through the shared memory, then redirect the call to real `libvulkan.so`

Note: For some APIs that invoke the use of address, I don't think it will be possible for Vulkan to access the memory of the real app.

Solution 3: same as solution 2, but for arguments that use address, allocate a temporary buffer in Vulkan "server" to pass to the real Vulkan API, then pass the buffer back to the fake Vulkan `.so` (Vulkan "client")

Note: Theorically possible, but not efficient

Again, dependencies hell :(